# How to close currently open tab on click in Chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Found the answer. It should be:

```
var currTab = tabs[0].id;
```

Original question:

I've recently started to learn about javascript and chrome extensions. I am trying to make it so that whenever the extension icon is clicked, it simply closes whichever tab is currently selected.

My code for my background.js file:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    var currTab = tabs[0];
    chrome.tabs.remove(currTab);
  });
});
```

And the manifest.json file

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "None",
  "description": "N/A",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Click to Close"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

So far, clicking the extension icon does absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chrome.tabs.remove(currTab.id);
```

`chrome.tabs.query` returns an array of these [Tab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab) objects but you only need the `tabId` when calling these functions.

The background page logs an error when you encounter this sort of type error in the Chrome APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to your manifest.json file:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that isn't doing it for me. I even set it to "persistent": false and tried that too.

Answer (score 0):

I edited the question to reflect the answer. It should be

```
var currTab = tabs[0].id; or even more simply var currTab = tab.id;
```